# How to prevent items to appear under fixed navbar in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, navbar, elementor

I'm using Astra template with Elementor plugin.

I've set up my navbar to be fixed - to scroll alongside the webpage, but now my items are appearing under it. And i'm not talking about the z-index issue, but the first thing that comes after navbar - breadcrumbs + title are both under navbar.

```
.main-header-bar-wrap{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

I solved the issue using --

```
padding-top:100px;
```

But i don't really think that's the best practice.

Is there any better solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really one foolproof way of doing this unfortunately. Fixed elements are taken completely out of the flow of the page and how it renders so don't take up any space. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/position#fixed

The way you've done it is one option, another is to change the padding to match the height on resizing the window (to make sure the height is always correct).

e.g. something like:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        $(".main").css("padding-top",$(".main-header-bar-wrap").outerHeight());
    })
```

The other option is to create a hidden duplicate of the header, with `position: relative` and `visibility: hidden`, which will take up the required space but not be visible. Just make sure to add the `aria-hidden="true"` property so people with screen readers don't end up with a duplicate menu.

You could do this with js as follows:

```
$( ".main-header-bar-wrap" ).after( 
       $(".main-header-bar-wrap").clone().addClass("spacer").attr("aria-hidden","true") 
);
```

This will duplicate the header and add the class `spacer` to the second version so you can style it separately with the `visibility` and `position` properties, along with the `aria-hidden` attribute.